# Align icon to the end of the button

Tags: angular-material2

Can you please show me the right way to put an icon at the very end of a button? Please see my code below:

**html**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="100px">
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1" >
        <div>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" flex class="expanded-button" style="text-align: left" [matMenuTriggerFor]="userprofile">
            <span>User Profile</span><mat-icon matSuffix style="float: right; position: relative;">chevron_right</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>

        <mat-menu #userprofile="matMenu" xPosition="before">
            <button mat-menu-item>View Profile</button>
            <button mat-menu-item >Change Password</button>
        </mat-menu>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

**css**

```
.expanded-button {
    display: block;
    width: 190px;
}

.icon-in-menu {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

With my codes above, this is what I get:

[image]

The arrow is not aligned with the text. Can you help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Angular Material now supports icon aligning:

```
<button mat-raised-button>
   <mat-icon iconPositionEnd>add</mat-icon> 
   Hello
</button>
```

A very late answer but worth mentioning it.

Comment: Would you mind giving a source ? it does work, but as I've spent quite some time looking for this exact information in angular material doc without finding it, I'm really curious where I could search for future problems as official doc appears to be outdated.

Comment: @Mozgor I agree with you ! I had the same issue and struggled a bit to find the solution... that's why I thought about sharing it in StackOverflow !

Well I was lucky enough to find an issue on Github that answers this question:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26253

It turns out they mentioned it on their migration guide ... not quite obvious !

Comment: I'll keep in mind to check their migration guide... thanks for the source & solution !

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just look through your code and simplify it a bit.

Hopefully this helps you out:

```
<button class="some-button">
  <span class="some-text">User Profile</span>
  <i class="some-icon">><i>
</button>

.some-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.some-text {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.some-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxQJjE

Comment: Have you tried removing the inline styles? You don't need the position relative and your mat-icon does not have the class icon-in-menu, so your css will not effect the icon.

Comment: Yes I did remove it. This is what I placed in the html => `<button mat-raised-button color="primary" flex class="expanded-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="userprofile">
            <span class="text-in-menu">User Profile</span>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="icon-in-menu">chevron_right</mat-icon>
          </button>`

Comment: @PaulAdam Consider using Stackblitz